# Bad counter path, pdhAddCounter; performance monitor in windows

Tags: c++, windows, performancecounter

I'm trying to count the number of processes on windoes 2008 server using pdh.h.

```
    CONST PWSTR COUNTER_PATH = L"\\System\\Processes";
    HQUERY hQuery = NULL;
    HCOUNTER hCounter;
    PDH_STATUS pdhStatus = ERROR_SUCCESS;

    pdhStatus = PdhOpenQuery(NULL, 0, &hQuery);
    pdhStatus = PdhAddCounter(hQuery, (LPCSTR)COUNTER_PATH, 0, &hCounter);
```

I got the COUNTER_PATH name from [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc737309%28v=ws.10%29), and the example can be found in [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa373228%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). But somehow I'm getting [0xC0000BC0 (PDH_CSTATUS_BAD_COUNTERNAME)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa373046%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) error message at PdhAddCounter. Can anybody pick up any mistake I made? I'm not sure what I'm missing here. Is there anything wrong with COUNTER_PATH?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're casting `COUNTER_PATH` to a `LPCSTR` in `PdhAddCounter` which you shouldn't be doing.

`PdhAddCounter`'s second parameter is a `LPCTSTR` which is the same as `CONST PWSTR`.

Comment: When I casted to LPCTSTR, it still generated the same problem. When I removed it completely, the compiler complained that "cannot convert parameter 2 from 'const PWSTR' to 'LPCSTR'".. In the example that I gave in the post, they don't cast anything at all. Do you think the problem is somewhat related to that?

Comment: It sounds like you've not enabled unicode.  If you switch on unicode (`Project Properties`->`Configuration Properties`->`General`->`Character Set`) and remove the cast it should work.  If you want unicode disabled, still remove the cast, but change your first line to `LPCSTR COUNTER_PATH = "\\System\\Processes";`